# Get list of revision ids ONLY

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, revision-history

I am trying to get a list of all the revision ids of a google sheet that has a lot of revisions, but when I execute GET [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[fileID]/revisions](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%5BfileID%5D/revisions), it gives me a lot of extra information that I don't need and only returns 200 revision numbers.

I've repeated the call with the nextPageToken multiple times which does pull more revision information but there is a lot of overlap from the previous one, so perhaps I am doing it wrong.

This is the exact HTTP post that I have been doing using the OAuth2.0 Playground.
[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[fileID]/revisions?maxresults=1000&nextPageToken="[token]"](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/%5BfileID%5D/revisions?maxresults=1000&nextPageToken=%22%5Btoken%5D%22)

I have tried multiple ways to isolate just the revision id using the fields parameter (revisionId, revisionsId, id, etc) but it doesn't recognize any of them, even though in the results that I get with all the other info, it is labeled as "id".

I saw this article on getting just the revision ID, but have not been able to replicate the results - https://www.rsaeks.com/?p=164

Is there a way to isolate just the revision id number in my results AND go through the pages without overlap?

My ultimate goal is to be able to download copies of each revision without having to go through each one in the version history and make a copy. If I could narrow it further to just versions that a specific user edited, that would be even better. I include this information in case there is another method of getting what I'm ultimately looking for that I'm not seeing or aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your concern about isolating just the revision id,

You are currently using [**Revisions: list in Drive API Version 2**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list)

The optional query parameters available in version 2 are:

**maxResults** - maximum number of revisions to return. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 200)

**pageToken** - page token for revisions. To get the next page of results, set this parameter to the value of "nextPageToken" from the previous response.

---

If you want to filter a specific field to be included in the response, you can use [**Revisions: list in Drive API Version 3**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list#try-it).

This version contains the following optional query parameters:

**fields** - The paths of the fields you want included in the response. If not specified, the response includes a default set of fields specific to this method. For development you can use the special value * to return all fields, but you'll
achieve greater performance by only selecting the fields you need. For more information, see Return specific fields for a file.

**pageSize** - The maximum number of revisions to return per page. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 200)

**pageToken** - The token for continuing a previous list request on the next page. This should be set to the value of 'nextPageToken' from the previous response.

---

## **Example:**

HTTP REQUEST:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FileId>/revisions?pageSize=1000&fields=revisions%2Fid&key=<Key>
```

[image]

SAMPLE RESPONSE:

```
 "revisions": [
  {
   "id": "1831"
  },
  {
   "id": "1835"
  },
  {
   "id": "1855"
  },
  {
   "id": "1856"
  },
  {
   "id": "1870"
  },
  {
   "id": "1892"
  },
  {
   "id": "1898"
  }
 ]
}
```

Note:
I wasn't able to reproduce your concern regarding the max results per page shown and the overlap between pages since I don't have a sample document with such revisions. But based on the documents provided, **pageSize** should set the maximum number of revisions to return per page where the maximum possible value that could be set is 1000 results.

If ever you will still need to use the **pageToken** parameter, you might need to include additional fields in the response (like the nextPageToken).
You can include multiple fields separated by comma.

**Sample field parameter:** kind, revisions/id

HTTP Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FileId>/revisions?pageSize=1000&fields=kind%2C%20revisions%2Fid&key=<Key>
```

Sample Response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#revisionList",
 "revisions": [
  {
   "id": "1831"
  },
  {
   "id": "1898"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful - figures it was something simple like being on the wrong version. One more question, if you would be so kind - is it possible to get a list of revision IDs just for revisions where a specific user was the one to modify it?

Comment: That is not possible. `Revisions.list()` gives you the complete list of revisions for a specific file, you can only filter what information you would like to receive as part of the response body. One workaround that you may use is to show relevant fields other than the revision id in the response body so that you can check each revision's **last modifying user**

Comment: You may use this as a field parameter to show important details about the user that modified the revision: `nextPageToken, revisions/id, revisions/modifiedTime, revisions/lastModifyingUser/displayName, revisions/lastModifyingUser/emailAddress`